# How to define a CheckConstraint for an integer field in SQLModel

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

Assume we have such atable. How we can define a [`CheckConstraint`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#check-constraint) for `age`?

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Column, String, Integer
from typing import Optional


class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "heroes"
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name: str = Field(sa_column=Column("name", String(32), unique=True), nullable=False)
    age: int = Field(sa_column=Column("age", ???Integer(gt=0)???))
```

Comment: Did you try giving `gt` directly to the `Field` constructor? `Field(gt=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using `sa_column`, you can construct your `Column` as you like. Meaning you just do `Column("age", Integer, CheckConstraint("age>0"))`.

Note that using `sa_column` will mean that the field ignores *all* other SQLAlchemy-related paramters including `nullable`, which means in your example the `name` field will actually end up being nullable because on a `Column` it is `nullable=True` by default. You need to specify `nullable=False` on the `Column` itself, not on the `Field`.

For `age` you could also just pass the `CheckConstraint` as a positional argument via `sa_column_args` instead of using `sa_column`. The SQL type `Integer` will be assigned by SQLModel by default because of the `int` annotation.

There is also no need for the `name` to be explicitly set as `"name"` on that `Column`. The attribute name is chosen by default.

Lastly, you don't need `nullable=False` on a field that has `primary_key=True`. The latter always implies the former.

Here is the code with my suggestions:

```py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field, Column, String, CheckConstraint
from typing import Optional


class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "heroes"
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field(sa_column=Column(String(32), unique=True, nullable=False))
    age: int = Field(sa_column_args=(CheckConstraint("age>0"),))
```

Resulting SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE heroes (
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    age INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (age>0), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    UNIQUE (name)
)
```